# UIView frame coming as zero (0 0; 0 0) when view appears second time

Tags: ios, uiview

I am using navigation controller (UINavigationController) for my iOS app and am using Storyboard.

I've several `UIView`s (that act as subViews) in my view controller (VC) and I have set outlet for those UIViews in Xcode.

My first VC in my navigation acts as a kind of Home (main page for the app).
All subViews of my second VC get displayed properly when second VC appears for the first time.
 But if I go to Home (or first VC) and come back to second VC then my subViews there don't display.

I've put a breakpoint in `viewWillAppear` method of second VC and below is frame description for one of the views.

First time: `frame = (20 20; 280 150)`
Go to Home VC and come to VC Second time: `frame = (0 0; 0 0)`

Can you please guide me how to debug this issue? Please let me know if any other info is required. Thanks.

Comment: override `setFrame:` and break on it

Comment: your view's size has changed during execution. So, you have use setFrame as below: ViewName.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

Comment: Thanks. Setting `frame` explicitly in `viewWillAppear` works as it sets frame of my UIView every time. But am unable to figure out what's breaking my frame in first place. Any pointer in that direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a view controller appears misaligned or some of the sub views seems missing when it loads second time then it means that something (am not able to figure out this) is breaking your layout (or something has changed your view's size during execution). So you set `frame`s (by using `frame` property) of `UIView`s in `viewWillAppear` method and it will work fine.

Thanks @mital and @xlc for the hint.